# merging matrices with cbind and match: name of the last column is dropped

Tags: r, matrix, merge, lapply, cbind

I have a list of matrices:

```
[[1]]
               a       b
X2005.06      NA 2504179
X2006.06      NA 3746905
X2007.06      NA 5468607
X2008.06      NA 6664545
X2009.06      NA 7339310
X2010.06 4602635 5587625
X2011.06 5188408 6498543
X2012.06 5190519 6831415
X2013.06 5246169 8214118
X2014.06 5856140 9384405

[[2]]
               c       d
X2005.06  354981 1729284
X2006.06  423136 1902213
X2007.06  602389 1902213
X2008.06  557095 1902213
X2009.06 -136485 2187545
X2010.06  469650 2665408
X2011.06  761031 2800000
X2012.06  246340 2800000
X2013.06  223661 2800000
X2014.06  698216 2800000
TTM      1340696 3052000

[[3]]
               e
X2005.06  489915
X2006.06  464280
X2007.06  576947
X2008.06  799941
X2009.06  817066
X2010.06 1261012
X2011.06 1134682
X2012.06  257973
X2013.06 1011744
X2014.06 1119384
TTM       163454
```

After merging this list of matrices into one merged matrix, I get following result:

```
               a       b       c       d        
X2005.06      NA 2504179  354981 1729284  489915
X2006.06      NA 3746905  423136 1902213  464280
X2007.06      NA 5468607  602389 1902213  576947
X2008.06      NA 6664545  557095 1902213  799941
X2009.06      NA 7339310 -136485 2187545  817066
X2010.06 4602635 5587625  469650 2665408 1261012
X2011.06 5188408 6498543  761031 2800000 1134682
X2012.06 5190519 6831415  246340 2800000  257973
X2013.06 5246169 8214118  223661 2800000 1011744
X2014.06 5856140 9384405  698216 2800000 1119384
```

Name of the last column should be "e" but it's dropped. Why?
For merging I'm using following code:

```
    Reduce(function(a, b) {
        ab <- cbind(a, b[match(rownames(a), rownames(b)), ])
        ab[order(rownames(ab)), ]
        ab
    }, Filter(is.matrix, x))
```

If I use `merge` function then result is correct:

```
    Reduce(function(a, b) as.matrix(transform(merge(a, b, by = 'row.names', all.x = T), row.names = Row.names, Row.names = NULL)), Filter(is.matrix, x))
```

output:

```
               a       b       c       d       e
X2005.06      NA 2504179  354981 1729284  489915
X2006.06      NA 3746905  423136 1902213  464280
X2007.06      NA 5468607  602389 1902213  576947
X2008.06      NA 6664545  557095 1902213  799941
X2009.06      NA 7339310 -136485 2187545  817066
X2010.06 4602635 5587625  469650 2665408 1261012
X2011.06 5188408 6498543  761031 2800000 1134682
X2012.06 5190519 6831415  246340 2800000  257973
X2013.06 5246169 8214118  223661 2800000 1011744
X2014.06 5856140 9384405  698216 2800000 1119384
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `drop=FALSE`. When there is a single column, you can keep the structure intact with `drop=FALSE` as it can change from `matrix` to `vector` by dropping the dimension attribute.

```
Reduce(function(a,b){
     ab <- cbind(a, b[match(rownames(a), rownames(b)), ,drop=FALSE])
     ab <- ab[order(rownames(ab)), ]
     ab
 },Filter(is.matrix, lst))
#               a       b       c       d       e
#X2005.06      NA 2504179  354981 1729284  489915
#X2006.06      NA 3746905  423136 1902213  464280
#X2007.06      NA 5468607  602389 1902213  576947
#X2008.06      NA 6664545  557095 1902213  799941
#X2009.06      NA 7339310 -136485 2187545  817066
#X2010.06 4602635 5587625  469650 2665408 1261012
#X2011.06 5188408 6498543  761031 2800000 1134682
#X2012.06 5190519 6831415  246340 2800000  257973
#X2013.06 5246169 8214118  223661 2800000 1011744
#X2014.06 5856140 9384405  698216 2800000 1119384
```

Comment: @EldarAgalarov  I am not sure how you got the result by wrapping with `lapply`.  I am not getting the expected output

Comment: That's because i'm using list of lists structure. For my example lapply wrapper can be dropped. I'll fix my post now.